# scala.js testing with jest

Tags: scala, unit-testing, scala.js, jestjs

https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/getting-started.html

Jest runner need a file with suffix .test/spec.js

sum.test.js

```
const sum = require('./sum');

test('adds 1 + 2 to equal 3', () => {
  expect(sum(1, 2)).toBe(3);
});
```

I achieved  something similar by creating new sjs project

```
package myapp.test

import scala.scalajs.js
import scala.scalajs.js.annotation.JSGlobalScope

object App {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    import Jest._
    test("add", () => {
      expect(1+ 2).toBe(3);
    })

  }
}


@JSGlobalScope
@js.native
object Jest extends js.Object {

  def test(str: String, function: js.Function0[_]): Unit = js.native

  def expect[T](in:T) : Matcher[T] = js.native
}

@js.native
trait Matcher[T] extends js.Object {

  def toBe(in:T):Unit = js.native
}
```

//build.sbt

```
artifactPath in Compile in fastOptJS := new File("./scalajs.test.js")

scalaJSLinkerConfig ~= (_.withModuleKind(ModuleKind.CommonJSModule))

scalaJSUseMainModuleInitializer := true
```

now `npm run test` running my tests , is it possible to achieve similar by writing tests in test/scala ?(without out creating a new separate project). Probably i am looking for a way to define `main method` for tests and `scalaJSUseMainModuleInitializer in Test  := true`  ? :s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is perfectly OK to define a `main` object/method in the `src/test/scala/` directory, and use

```scala
scalaJSUseMainModuleInitializer in Test := true
```

To run it, use `test:run` from sbt.